# Laravel simple program

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel.

- ../laraone/public/ is working but cannot go further to create a simple aboutus page without the use of controller.
- What is the pattern of URL to be used to get aboutus page.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses MVC architecture. So to create a page you must go through A Controller and View (Model if you want to use DB and do data processing).

**Soltuion # 1**

You have to create a route first (Assuming Laravel 5.2):

```
// app/Http/routes.php  in later version there is a separate folder for routes. 
    project_root/routes/web.php

Route::get('about-us','HomeController@aboutUs');
```

Controller :

```
// app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php

  public function aboutUs(){
       return view('pages.aboutus'); //this will look for views/pages/aboutus.blade.php
  }
```

View:

```
   project_root/views/pages/aboutus.blade.php //put you html in this file
```

**Solution # 2**

Route:

```
    // app/Http/routes.php  in later version there is a separate folder for routes. 
    project_root/routes/web.php

Route::get('about-us', function () {
      return view('pages.aboutus'); //this will look for views/pages/aboutus.blade.php
 });
```

View:

```
   project_root/views/pages/aboutus.blade.php //put you html in this file
```

Solution # 2 is not recommended but does the job. If you are new to laravel and learning it go for Solution # 1

Comment: I have done Solution #2, but it returns 'Sorry the link you used is invalid.'

Comment: Thank you for replying.....I have done Solution #2, but it returns 'Sorry the link you used is invalid'. The URL I used in the browser is "ip_address/laraone/about" in the server. View path is "/var/www/html/laraone/resources/views/pages"

Comment: Try adding public between laraone and about